# Javascript source error, cannot find it, Please assist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an error on line 30. Which is the end of the file.

I obviously missed some closing bracket or something, but I have no idea, I am going insane. Please assist.

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ajaxpager .pager  a').live('click', function() {
        href = $(this).attr('href');
        //    display = href.indexOf('display');
        display = "pager-display";
        if (href.indexOf('?') == -1) {
            href += '?';
        };
        href += '&ajax=1';
        $('#' + display).ajaxStart(function() {
            var html = '<div>';
            html += '<img src="' + Drupal.settings.rlisting['loadingimage'] + '" border="0" />';
            html += '</div>';
            $(this).html(html);
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: href,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#' + display).hide().html(result).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: You don't have a closing bracket/paren for your `$(document).ready`

Comment: Yeah, always remember to use proper indentation...

Comment: As i know, "live()" method is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the closing brackets at the end

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ajaxpager .pager  a').live('click', function() {
            href = $(this).attr('href');
            //    display = href.indexOf('display');
            display = "pager-display";
            if (href.indexOf('?') == -1) {
                href += '?';
            };
            href += '&ajax=1';
            $('#' + display).ajaxStart(function() {
                var html = '<div>';
                html += '<img src="' + Drupal.settings.rlisting['loadingimage'] + '" border="0" />';
                html += '</div>';
                $(this).html(html);
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: href,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#' + display).hide().html(result).fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    }); // <-- HERE 
})(jQuery);
```

​

Comment: It should come before the `})(jQuery);`

Comment: @Musa Ah yes my mistake.. corected

Answer (score 1):

remove the `$(document).ready(function() {`

if you change `.live` to `.on` then you don't need to bind the function when the DOM is ready.